# Android change SDK version in Eclipse? Unable to resolve target android-x

Tags: eclipse, android

I developed an Android aplication against 2.1 SDK. Since then I have re-installed Eclipse/Android SDK; with the new install, I want to 'upgrade' the dependancy of the Android application to 2.2 SDK (because I dont want 2.1 installed on my machine). Is this possible? I am getting the following error from eclipse:

```
[2010-08-31 18:18:32 - AndroidApplication] Unable to resolve target 'android-7'
```

Answer (score 59):

If you're using eclipse you can open `default.properties` file in your workspace and change the project target to the new sdk (`target=android-8` for 2.2).  I accidentally selected the 1.5 sdk for my version and didn't catch it until much later, but updating that and restarting eclipse seemed to have done the trick.

Comment: I also had to change <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="..."/> in my AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Also update file "project.properties" in project directory, it worked for me only after changing it.

Answer (score 15):

go to project properties and change the target from 7 to 8 also change the target in android manifest and also go to properties of project by right clicking on the project and choose the target

Comment: +1 if you don't want to change default properties, just the sdk version for one or two projects.

Answer (score 7):

This can happen when you mistakenly import an Android project into your Eclipse workspace as a Java project.  The solution in this case: delete the project from the workspace in the Package Explorer, then go to File -> Import -> Android -> Existing Android code into workspace.

Answer (score 5):

I faced the same issue and got it working.

I think it is because when you import a project, build target is not set in the project properties which then default to the value used in manifest file. Most likely, you already have installed a later android API with your SDK.

The solution is to enable build target toward your installed API level (but keep the minimum api support as specified in the manifest file). TO do this, in project properties, go to android, and from "Project Build Target", pick a target name.

Answer (score 3):

In Build: v22.6.2-1085508 ADT you need to add(select Android 4.4.2)

Goto project --> properties --> Android(This is second in listed item order leftPanel) and in the RightPanel Project Build Target, select Android 4.4.2 as Target name and apply changes
It will rebuild the workspace.

In my case **unable to resolve target 'android-17'** eclipse was being shown as compile error and in code: import java.util.HashMap was not being referenced.

Answer (score 2):

This Problem is because of Path so you need to build the path using following Steps

Goto project ----->Right Click on Project Name ---->properties ---->click on Than **Java Build Path** option than ---> click Android 4.2.2---->Ok

Answer (score 1):

Goto project -->properties --> (in the dialog box that opens goto Java build path), and in order and export select android 4.1 (your new version) and select dependencies.