# How to resolve build path errors?

Tags: android, buildpath

If I run my project this error will come build path problem how to solve this error.

error:

1. Description Resource Path Location
   Type Project 'videothumb' is missing
   required source      folder: 'gen'
   videothumb Build path Build Path
   Problem
2. The project cannot be built until
   build path errors are resolved
   videothumb Unknown      Java Problem

Can any one help me?

[image]

Comment: Are you using any IDE like eclipse?

Comment: Upgrade you "android-sdk" i think there are mission files, then clean ::::: Android tools -> Add support libraries

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try to clean project and if it still doesn't help close and then open project.

Comment: It is not working with you and it the best answer, that is great

Comment: Not sure why this is accepted as a solution when it didn't solve your problem.. Nor did it solve mine.

Answer (score 7):

IF you are using eclipse then do as follows:

1. right click your project.
2. select `build path-->configure build path`.
3. update all the broken links in all 4 tabs.
4. Go to `project-->clean`      [project will be found at top menu of eclipse.]
5. Clean your project.

Its done. For any further explanation comment on my answer.

Hope this helps.

**Edit:**

Here you go:

[image]

As you can see i'm at source tab of configure build path and i have only one folder here named  ATalk/Src. likewise you can have number of folders.

Check for red cross mark on folder. if its there then your folder path is wrong means link is broken for that folder.

Same way you can check in Libraries tab. There you will find list of jars in your project. If any of them have red cross then its path is missing. So update all such red cross paths.

As you can see i dont have a red cross on my folder means it is at correct location.

Hope you get my point.

Comment: @bala: are you sure you have correct "videothumb" folder in Source tab of configure build path ???

Comment: i think i make mistake in 3rd point because i am not clear can u explain or post screen shot how to update all the broken links in all 4 tabs

Comment: ok sdk location indicate error                                   Could not find /home/embdes/projects/android/android-sdk-linux_86/tools/adb!  i think this is the problem now i am post that screen shot in my page

Comment: @bala: by looking at your screen shot i can only say: "update your SDK path that points to correct location." Make sure SDK is located at the path given there.

Comment: ok if dont mine how to update please tell me because if i click install/update its indicate in this line: This currently displayed page contains invalid values...

Comment: @bala: you can browse for your SDK location. Click on the "Browse" button in your screen shot.

Comment: @bala: Tell me what happens if you do this. Does it let you change the  path?

Comment: its not working its indicate same error any other solution sir

Comment: @bala: try creating similar project in a clean workspace, that means create a new workspace, and then copy all the .settings-files, .project and .classpath from the newly created workspace to the problematic workspace that is your current workspace. Let me know the out put.

Comment: now its working fine. and one more doubt now i am download one open source project if i run that project its indicate this error how to configure? error is 1.Unable to resolve target 'android-5' Android Target Problem

Comment: @bala: you will find answer on this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3614190/android-change-sdk-version-in-eclipse-unable-to-resolve-target-android-x

Comment: i got it...do u know ndk and jni use can u give clear explanation to me

Comment: @bala: will you please elaborate what you wanna exactly achieve? Whats your problem regarding ndk and jni?

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:**
I just noticed that, according to your screenshot, the problem seems to be that the `adb` tool is not found. Now I might be wrong but I think that as of Android 2.3 (maybe even earlier) the `adb` tool is expected to be in `[path-to-your-sdk]/platform-tools` folder, not in the `[path-to-your-sdk]/tools` folder. The later path was used in earlier SDK's and your problem might be caused by such a simple thing that you have an outdated Android plugin in Eclipse.

**OLD, IRRELEVANT ANSWER:**
I've seen these kind of issues in Eclipse environments when I have some kind of error in my XML files. Malformed errors (that violate the rules of the XML structure) are often treated as "syntax errors" and are shown directly when you write them or when you try to build your application.

Other errors, however, like giving invalid references (giving a dimension where an integer is expected, for example) are not always highlighted with file name and failing line number (I'm not sure if this is bug in Eclipse's android plugin or even if it's a bug at all).

These kind of errors you'll have to hunt down manually and rebuild your project (as dcave555 sugested). This is really boring work if you have many XML files with many changes in

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because of your Android build path settings. Try to check:

> Window > Prefereces > Android > Build path

it should properly set to your Android SDK

Comment: yes its not set properly now i am edit my content and post that error screen

Answer (score 0):

I think the path should look like this: `/home/embdes/projects/android/android-sdk-linux_86`