# My App Won't load on the Android Emulator on Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator, device, android-virtual-device

I am using the latest Eclipse

I tried two apps "hello world" and an Augment reality one.

Not sure if if this will help the coding but I am also not sure if "Device" matters on this Emulator.

I can only use an Emulator since I don'y have a link cable.

```
 [2014-01-02 19:32:12 - SDK Manager] Created AVD 'AVD4' based on Android 4.3, ARM   
      (armeabi-v7a) processor,
     [2014-01-02 19:32:12 - SDK Manager] with the following hardware config:
    [2014-01-02 19:32:12 - SDK Manager] hw.sdCard=no
    [2014-01-02 19:32:12 - SDK Manager] hw.device.manufacturer=Generic
    [2014-01-02 19:32:12 - SDK Manager] hw.mainKeys=yes
   [2014-01-02 19:32:12 - SDK Manager] hw.lcd.density=240
[2014-01-02 19:32:12 - SDK Manager] hw.accelerometer=yes
[2014-01-02 19:32:12 - SDK Manager] hw.dPad=no
[2014-01-02 19:32:12 - SDK Manager] hw.device.hash=1265634471
[2014-01-02 19:32:12 - SDK Manager] hw.trackBall=no
[2014-01-02 19:32:12 - SDK Manager] hw.device.name=4in WVGA (Nexus S)
[2014-01-02 19:32:12 - SDK Manager] hw.camera.back=none
[2014-01-02 19:32:12 - SDK Manager] hw.sensors.proximity=yes
[2014-01-02 19:32:12 - SDK Manager] hw.battery=yes
[2014-01-02 19:32:12 - SDK Manager] disk.dataPartition.size=200M
[2014-01-02 19:32:12 - SDK Manager] hw.audioInput=yes
[2014-01-02 19:32:12 - SDK Manager] hw.sensors.orientation=yes
[2014-01-02 19:32:12 - SDK Manager] hw.gps=yes
[2014-01-02 19:32:12 - SDK Manager] skin.dynamic=yes
[2014-01-02 19:32:12 - SDK Manager] hw.keyboard=yes
[2014-01-02 19:32:12 - SDK Manager] vm.heapSize=32
[2014-01-02 19:32:12 - SDK Manager] hw.ramSize=512
[2014-01-02 19:33:55 - DreamFragmentTest] ------------------------------
[2014-01-02 19:33:55 - DreamFragmentTest] Android Launch!
[2014-01-02 19:33:55 - DreamFragmentTest] adb is running normally.
[2014-01-02 19:33:55 - DreamFragmentTest] Performing com.example.dreamfragmenttest.MainActivity activity launch
[2014-01-02 19:33:55 - DreamFragmentTest] Automatic Target Mode: launching new emulator with compatible AVD 'AVD4'
[2014-01-02 19:33:55 - DreamFragmentTest] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'AVD4'
[2014-01-02 19:34:18 - Emulator] emulator: emulator window was out of view and was recentered
[2014-01-02 19:34:18 - Emulator] 
[2014-01-02 19:34:18 - DreamFragmentTest] New emulator found: emulator-5554
[2014-01-02 19:34:18 - DreamFragmentTest] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...
[2014-01-02 20:04:42 - DreamFragmentTest] HOME is up on device 'emulator-5554'
[2014-01-02 20:04:42 - DreamFragmentTest] Uploading DreamFragmentTest.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2014-01-02 20:04:44 - DreamFragmentTest] Installing DreamFragmentTest.apk...
[2014-01-02 20:06:42 - AndARSampleProject] Unable to resolve target 'android-4'
[2014-01-02 20:07:09 - DreamFragmentTest] Failed to install DreamFragmentTest.apk on device 'emulator-5554!
[2014-01-02 20:07:09 - DreamFragmentTest] (null)
[2014-01-02 20:07:10 - DreamFragmentTest] Launch canceled!
[2014-01-02 20:28:34 - SDK Manager] Created AVD 'AVD4' based on Android 4.3, ARM (armeabi-v7a) processor,
[2014-01-02 20:28:34 - SDK Manager] with the following hardware config:
[2014-01-02 20:28:34 - SDK Manager] hw.sdCard=no
[2014-01-02 20:28:34 - SDK Manager] hw.device.manufacturer=Generic
[2014-01-02 20:28:34 - SDK Manager] hw.mainKeys=no
[2014-01-02 20:28:34 - SDK Manager] hw.lcd.density=160
[2014-01-02 20:28:34 - SDK Manager] hw.accelerometer=yes
[2014-01-02 20:28:34 - SDK Manager] hw.dPad=no
[2014-01-02 20:28:34 - SDK Manager] hw.device.hash=1350518763
[2014-01-02 20:28:34 - SDK Manager] hw.trackBall=no
[2014-01-02 20:28:34 - SDK Manager] hw.device.name=10.1in WXGA (Tablet)
[2014-01-02 20:28:34 - SDK Manager] hw.camera.back=none
[2014-01-02 20:28:34 - SDK Manager] hw.sensors.proximity=yes
[2014-01-02 20:28:34 - SDK Manager] hw.battery=yes
[2014-01-02 20:28:34 - SDK Manager] disk.dataPartition.size=200M
[2014-01-02 20:28:34 - SDK Manager] hw.audioInput=yes
[2014-01-02 20:28:34 - SDK Manager] hw.sensors.orientation=yes
[2014-01-02 20:28:34 - SDK Manager] hw.camera.front=none
[2014-01-02 20:28:34 - SDK Manager] hw.gps=yes
[2014-01-02 20:28:34 - SDK Manager] skin.dynamic=yes
[2014-01-02 20:28:34 - SDK Manager] hw.keyboard=yes
[2014-01-02 20:28:34 - SDK Manager] vm.heapSize=32
[2014-01-02 20:28:34 - SDK Manager] hw.ramSize=512
[2014-01-02 20:28:48 - DreamFragmentTest] ------------------------------
[2014-01-02 20:28:48 - DreamFragmentTest] Android Launch!
[2014-01-02 20:28:48 - DreamFragmentTest] adb is running normally.
[2014-01-02 20:28:48 - DreamFragmentTest] Performing com.example.dreamfragmenttest.MainActivity activity launch
[2014-01-02 20:28:48 - DreamFragmentTest] Automatic Target Mode: launching new emulator with compatible AVD 'AVD4'
[2014-01-02 20:28:48 - DreamFragmentTest] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'AVD4'
[2014-01-02 20:29:14 - Emulator] emulator: emulator window was out of view and was recentered
[2014-01-02 20:29:14 - Emulator] 
[2014-01-02 20:29:14 - DreamFragmentTest] New emulator found: emulator-5554
[2014-01-02 20:29:14 - DreamFragmentTest] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...
[2014-01-02 21:04:08 - DreamFragmentTest] HOME is up on device 'emulator-5554'
[2014-01-02 21:04:08 - DreamFragmentTest] Uploading DreamFragmentTest.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2014-01-02 21:04:10 - DreamFragmentTest] Installing DreamFragmentTest.apk...
[2014-01-02 21:07:05 - DreamFragmentTest] Failed to install DreamFragmentTest.apk on device 'emulator-5554!
[2014-01-02 21:07:05 - DreamFragmentTest] (null)
[2014-01-02 21:07:07 - DreamFragmentTest] Launch canceled!
```

Comment: [See these answers for possible solutions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3614190/android-change-sdk-version-in-eclipse-unable-to-resolve-target-android-x)

Comment: Let me try it, thank you

Comment: No problem. If one of those work for you then you can upvote the appropriate one and post the solution that worked for you here as an answer. Well I guess you can't upvote but you can acknowledge the answer that helped.

Answer (score 0):

Try cleaning the project (Project --> Clean), restarting everything, and retrying again.

Comment: No problem... Let me know how it turns out!

Comment: I may have messed up because now it won't run

Comment: No but started using Corona and outlaw but new problems persist

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to increase the Virtual Memory Heap to 64 ? The APIs seem to be more and more demanding as their level increases. It solved my problem with Android 4.4.