# How to check whether my SMS app is default in Android

Tags: android, sms, default

I want to check whether my SMS app is set as default app in android. I am following this tutorial:

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2013/10/getting-your-sms-apps-ready-for-kitkat.html

I can set my SMS app as default SMS app by the following code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, Sms.Intents.ACTION_CHANGE_DEFAULT);
intent.putExtra(Sms.Intents.EXTRA_PACKAGE_NAME, context.getPackageName());
startActivity(intent);
```

But I want to check whether my SMS app is set as default app. How can I do that?

Comment: Check the return from `Telephony.Sms.getDefaultSmsPackage(context)` against your package name.

Comment: The following error is showed : "Telephony cannot be resolved" . How can I solve this issue ?

Comment: `import android.provider.Telephony;`

Comment: The import android.provider.Telephony cannot be resolved

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [getDefaultSmsPackage (Context context)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Telephony.Sms.html#getDefaultSmsPackage(android.content.Context)):

> Used to determine the currently configured default SMS package.

For example:

```
public static boolean isDefaultSmsApp(Context context) {
    return context.getPackageName().equals(Telephony.Sms.getDefaultSmsPackage(context));
}
```

Comment: The following error is showed : "Telephony cannot be resolved" . How can I solve this issue ?

Comment: Your `compileSdkVersion` need to be at least 19

Comment: If you are using Android Studio open your `app/build.gradle` and change the value of `compileSdkVersion`. If you are using Eclipse see this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3809943/2837959)

Comment: how to check for older version below 19?